# Repeating TABs on subsequent lines in text files (but keeping TABs disabled for code)

Tags: emacs, tabs

I am editing a text file `foo.txt` using emacs.

I press <kbd>C-q TAB</kbd> to insert a <kbd>TAB</kbd> character at the beginning of a line and then follow with a few characters.

Once I press ENTER, emacs inserts eight spaces on the following line.

How do I specify in my .emacs that I would like TABs to be repeated on subsequent lines with TABs?

**Importantly**, I dislike TAB characters in program code, and so I have `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` to make sure that TABs are inserted only when I explicitly ask for them.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs inserts `SPC` chars because you told it to, by setting `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil` (my preference too, BTW).

If you want Emacs to indent using `TAB` chars in a particular mode (buffer), but you want it to use `SPC` chars in general (i.e., in other modes), then set `indent-tabs-mode` to `t` in those modes where you want `TAB`s.  Just use `setq` when you are in the mode, since it is a buffer-local variable. For example:

```
 (add-hook MY-mode-hook (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
```

Comment: Now I get spaces in c-mode and tabs in text-mode, but despite making an exclusion just for text-mode as you suggested, I am getting tabs in lisp code. Let me write a more precise update to the question.

Comment: @Calaf: Perhaps because of mode inheritance, i.e., perhaps your lisp mode inherits ultimately from text mode (or whatever you used for `MY-mde-hook`). You will need to look into it more closely.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is: No, there is no way to do this by some simple configuration setting in emacs. `indent-tabs-mode` is either on or off, and indentation will behave according to that.

But, just because this feature is not there, doesn't mean you can't add it!

This is actually not a simple problem from what I found. Whether or not to use tabs or spaces is determined by `indent-tabs-mode` in C mostly. Assuming that you are running a recent version of emacs, the auto indentation is coming from `electric-indent-mode` which uses `indent-according-to-mode` in a `post-self-insert-hook` to do the indentation.

What I did for this was define a buffer local minor mode, when this mode is active `indent-tabs-mode` will be temporarily set depending on the first character in the last line while running `indent-according-to-mode`.

So when `smart-electric-indent-tabs-mode` is active, and your last line started with the tab, the next line will indent with a tab too, else it will just use whatever `indent-tabs-mode` would normally be set to.

You could add the following to your config to activate it. The `add-hook` clause is put in there for your convenience, you can activate it on the fly like a normal minor mode if you'd like.

```lisp
(define-minor-mode smart-electric-indent-tabs-mode
  "When on, indenting will use tabs if the current line does,
    else it will indent according to `indent-tabs-mode'."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " smart-tabs"
  :keymap nil
  :global nil)

 (defadvice indent-according-to-mode (around maybe-use-tabs activate)
  "Follow `smart-electric-indent-tabs-mode'."
  (let ((indent-tabs-mode
         (or (and smart-electric-indent-tabs-mode
                  (save-excursion
                    (save-restriction
                      (widen)
                      (beginning-of-line 0)
                      (looking-at "\t"))))
             indent-tabs-mode)))
    ad-do-it))

;; if you want, add a text mode hook
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'smart-electric-indent-tabs-mode)
```

This has only been tested to work during electric indentation

Comment: That's looking pretty good. I'm not sure why it's not accepted, as it actually does what was requested. The code formatting is a little out; you might want to re-indent it?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it was enjoyable to write either way. I reformatted the code in emacs and nothing changed so idk about that.

Comment: That's very odd. The `and` body clauses are clearly not in alignment. Emacs should have indented `(save-excursion` to the same column as the `smart-electric-indent-tabs-mode` above it. Does it look okay in your browser?

Comment: Found the issue. I use pretty-mode to map things like "and" to their mathy symbols. This changes indentation since "and" is displayed as only 1 character, but when you copy the text, the whole word is copied, not the pretty symbol, hence the error when copy and pasting the code.