# Following up emacs TAB indentation with TABs, not spaces

Tags: emacs, tabs

If my .emacs contains just the lines

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(add-hook 'text-mode-common-hook
          (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
```

I am expecting that if I edit a file `list.txt` containing

```
<tab> - Item 1
<tab> - Item 2
```

and press <kbd>return</kbd> after Item 2, a tab will be inserted on the next line, and not eight spaces.

But I get eight spaces, not a `TAB`.

How do I modify the .emacs above (for 24.5, if it matters) so that I get TABs?

Needless to say, I am trying to avoid <kbd>C-q TAB</kbd>. The idea is to automate the insertion of <kbd>C-q TAB</kbd> after a <kbd>return</kbd>, when needed.

Does something so simple really require smart-tabs?

I have asked this question in the past and was [told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25021888/704972) that a .emacs such as the one above would solve the problem. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`text-mode-common-hook` doesn't seem to exist](https://www.google.ca/#q=emacs+%22text-mode-common-hook%22). There is `text-mode-hook`, though.

This should work:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
```